# Connecting the GPX track points

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid, gpx

I am trying to draw a track on a OpenStreetMap in android. I am able to record the location and export it as a GPX file. I am also able to extract the latitude and longitude from the gpx file and overlay it as coordinates in the OSM. My question is, I am able to show only the coordinates of the trackpoints but I don't know how to connect these points to show as a route. Can somehow help me if you have achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

As alternative, you can have a look at [skmaps]:

- check the tracks menu in the [demo project](http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download)
- if you have the route points/list of segments, then you can draw them on the map using a SkPolyline - see the getting started chapter: http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/android#sec009

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OSMBonusPack](https://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/) Polyline overlay.